# Webapi how to have a name the json response instead starting with JSON

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, fiddler

I have developed an asp.net webapi and testing it using fiddler. I am getting a response as shown below:

Instead of this

```
{
  "name":"A",
  "age":"B"
}
```

Can it be changed as below?

```
User{
    "name":"A",
    "age":"B"
}
```

But instead of the response starting with JSON, i would like to have the custom name. Can anyone help how to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "the custom name"? And that's not JSON.

Comment: Do i need to wrap the response in a class to get a name?

Comment: Do you mean `{ "User" : { ... } }` or do you deliberately want to return invalid JSON? If the former, then yes, simply introduce a "wrapper" or "container" class containing one property: `public User User { get; set; }`.

Comment: yes it is like the former. ok i will introduce a wrapper or container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to want to wrap your response in a "wrapper" or "container" class. Given your current class and response looks like this:

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public User Get(int id)
{
    return _userRepository.Find(id);
}
```

Then you can simply add this wrapper class:

```
public class UserContainer
{
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

And in your controller wrap it:

```
public UserContainer Get(int id)
{
    var user = _userRepository.Find(id);
    return new UserContainer
    {
        User = user
    }
}
```

This will make your response look like this:

```
{
    "User" :
    {
        "Name" : "Foo",
        "Age" : 42
    }
}
```

But do note that this is semantically unnecessary. The client is already calling the `/api/user/42` endpoint, so they'd expect a user back. There's no need to indicate that in your JSON again.

Comment: Thank you. I think i can use if i am returning users as array. In that case apart from other properties can i exclude this User name to exclude camelcase thing?

Comment: You can use the `[JsonProperty]` to rename properties, and you don't need a wrapper for arrays as well; just return an `IEnumerable<User>`.

Comment: Ok. Thank you again.